# Connecting HTML5 GUI events to Qt application

Tags: html, qt, svg, qwebview

My existing Qt application has a 'traditional' GUI comprising panels with QtWidgets. I now want to add a GUI panel which will involve dragging 2D bezier curve points around, with various types of graphical feedback.

My first choice for the new GUI would be HTML5, JavaScript and SVG. Using a library such as [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) or [Ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/). I can develop this GUI more easily than I could by developing a QtWidget (implementing QGraphicsScene) to do it - plus with the HTML5 route I would be able to re-use the code in an online version of the app.

Despite [Qt's website saying that I can develop my whole UI with HTML5](http://qt.digia.com/Product/User-Interface-Creation-with-Qt/HTML5/) I can find no examples of how I would receive events or signals on the C++ side from user actions - or how I could expose a C++ method to a JavaScript object in the WebView.

Is the only way I can communicate between a web UI and the application by implementing a web server on the C++ side and using AJAX requests from the JavaScript back to the parent application?

Comment: Have you even looked at the graphics view/scene framework in Qt, and the examples that are available within Qt Creator? Because there is an example that does exactly what you want. Just browse the wonderful examples included with Qt - they're well worth it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have and I agree it certainly *can* achieve what I need. Without getting into a debate over the merits of JS/SVG coding over Qt/QGraphicsScene coding, for me personally I prefer the HTML5 route, which will also give more options in the future. I've edited my question to clarify this and the fact that - as you point out - QGraphicsScene is the obvious *Qt* choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what I need is the [addToJavaScriptWindowObject](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject) method of [QWebFrame](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebframe.html), which makes a Qt object available to the JavaScript, exposing its properties and methods.

An example of this in use is the [Form Extractor Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitwidgets-formextractor-example.html).

Comment: According to [this document](http://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/presentation_pdf/Webkit.pdf), `QtWebKit` likely to be fully or partially deprecated after Qt 5.3. The solution above doesn't work with `QtWebEngine`.

Answer (score 2):

In case any other person, like me, stumbles upon about this question in Qt 5.X days, QtWebKit is deprecated.

Now, we have to use [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html),a Chromium based rendering engine, and [QtWebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-index.html) in order to communicate back and forth with Qt and HTML-Js.

There are some nice examples in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-examples.html), as always.